# Pass parameters from Push Notification to View

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have a view with a webview, which should be called when clicking on a corresponding push notification and a parameter with a URL. The URL should then be called in the Webview. How can I pass the parameter from the push notification to the view so that the URL is called in the Webview?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it via the [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) used to open your `WebView` from the notification (details see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)). 
You can set extras to that `PendingIntent` like you would with a 'normal' `Intent` when [passing data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application).